# Best way to display a long list of static values

Tags: website-design, grid

I am creating a grid-style list of attributes for a complex tool. Each line gives their name, data type, description, and their respective lists of values (LOVs). However, the LOVs can range from 1-2 options to over 200 (i.e. country lists). However, the stakeholder wants a way to quickly view these attributes and their LOVs, but displaying them as a grid with all of the values doesn't work well when there are massive amounts of values. What is the best way to display them? I try to avoid pop-ups, but I feel like displaying all of them in the cell is a less desirable option. Here is an example of what we have so far:

[image]

Comment: Are they choosing or just viewing? choosing: can you get a drop-down in there? viewing: hover over for preview?

Comment: They want to view and possibly copy the list. They are not manipulating the data or editing anything.

Comment: What environment is this? Web, application, mobile?

Comment: Master detail.  A drop down list with 5-20 works in a grid.  But for a long list I like separate detail for the selected item.  You may have other fields that are truncated.  ... is pretty standard to represent truncated.

Comment: @Chris it's web

Comment: @Blam we ended up going with a modal list dialog so that it doesn't redirect the screen but is still accessible.

Answer (score 1):

I would provide the values as you have in your screenshot if there are sufficiently few, but if there are too many, show the first one or two with a "and n others". In that case, make it both clickable (as you have in your screenshot) and perhaps include a `[+]` icon just prior that would expand an indented/child row below that row with a grid with all the LOV values (or the `[+]` could be at the beginning of the row but only enabled/visible if there are too many values to fit in the Values column)

Answer (score 1):

A list can be displayed as in figure 1. When there are more than 5 items, you could add the link "more" clicking on which would show the next 5 items as in figure 2.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fF6uMH.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Further, if the items tend to go beyond 10 items, you could give a **search** option as in figure 3, within the list frame, to help users search for items quickly.

Also if at all the users have to make multiple selections from the list to copy (as you have mentioned in the comment), then it would be better to have the items displayed with **checkbox**, so that all the checked items get selected and copied and then allowing the user to paste the copied items list where needed.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using Master Detail layout. When the user clicks on a row in the LOVs list (Master) the details are displayed in a sperate list (Detail). You can have both lists in the same window either top/bottom or Left/Right.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fn0n0A.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>